# FOR Loop in R for a random vector

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to write a loop using "for" where my index,i, should have values from a set of values c(2,4,6,8,10,12) . I am further using i for subsetting values from another vector.

I defined a vector X ,  where X <- c(2,4,,6,8,10,12) , 
and then using for(i in X[1]:tail(X,n=1)).

This results in i taking all values from 2 to 12!
Whereas I want it to take the values mentioned in X only, i.e 2,4,6,8,10,12.

I hope someone can give me a hint how to do this

Thank you in advanced

Comment: `X[1]:tail(X, n=1)` is the same as `2:12`

Comment: `for (val in values) {}` will work (Assuming values is seq(2,12,2)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through a sequence. If you want to loop only through the values of a vector, use this:

```
X <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
for(i in X) {
  # Your code
}
```